# How to find vector elements between two points in matrix

Tags: matrices

To give you some context, a small part of my program needs to calculate which map tiles to load based on a rectangle selection.

Imagine I have a 4x4 2d plane with values

```
┏━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┓
┃ (1,1) ┃ (1,2) ┃ (1,3) ┃ (1,4) ┃
┣━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━┫
┃ (2,1) ┃ (2,2) ┃ (2,3) ┃ (2,4) ┃
┣━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━┫
┃ (3,1) ┃ (3,2) ┃ (3,3) ┃ (3,4) ┃
┣━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━┫
┃ (4,1) ┃ (4,2) ┃ (4,3) ┃ (4,4) ┃
┗━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━┛
```

Now I have two corner values `(4,2)` for SW and `(2,4)` for NW side. How do I get `(2,2), (2,3), (2,4), (3,2), (3,3), (3,4), (4,2), (4,3), (4,4)` as a result?

I could create a loop that would iterate over the values as I know that min X and A is 2 (which makes it (2,2) and max is 4 which makes is (4,4) so I could just iterate over the values, I was just curious if there's a simpler mathematical solution.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I've read your question several times, but I'm still not sure what you're stating & asking. For example, you write "Now I have two corner values `(4,2)` for NW and `(2,4)` for SE side." However, the NW corner value shown is `(1,1)` and the SE corner value is `(4,4)`. Also, these are corners, so I'm not sure what you mean by "SE side" part at the end of the sentence. In addition, what do you mean by asking "How do I get ..."? In what manner are you trying to "get" those values. Thanks, in advance, for clarifying, & I apologize if I'm missing something fairly simple & obvious.

Comment: Thanks @JohnOmielan Sorry I've just realized that I've made an error in my question. It were supposed to say (4,2) for SW (Bottom left corner of my selection) and (2,4) for NW (Top right corner of my selection). Image a rectangle selection that starts from one corner to an opposite one only for a subset of values. I am selecting values between a corner (4,2) to (2,4). By the 'how do I get' I meant what's the calculation to get those values. I am able to program this but I was thinking that there must be a mathematical function to do that and I was just curious which one.

Answer (score 0):

in C++ you could do something like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    //input
    int corner_SW [2] = {4,2};
    int corner_NE [2] = {2,4};

    //calculation
    for(int i = corner_NE[0]; i <= corner_SW[0]; i++)
    {
        for(int j = corner_SW[1]; j <= corner_NE[1]; j++)
        {
            cout << '(' << i << ',' << j << ')'; 
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

run [this](https://rextester.com/UKF4872) and you get:

(2,2)(2,3)(2,4)

(3,2)(3,3)(3,4)

(4,2)(4,3)(4,4)

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to iterate without going out of bounds? If so, a common trick is to pad your matrix with 0's. So you'll end up with a 6x6 matrix with 0's on the edges.